# Karma opening window

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm using this, to open a new tab:

```
$window.open($scope.jobInviteData.externalLink);
```

The problem is that I'm using Karma to test, and it's opening a new window.
How can I make karma not open any windows?

Answer (score 4):

You would want to mock the $window service:

```
var windowmock;
beforeEach(module("myModule",function ($provide) {
    $provide.service('$window', function () {
        windowmock = jasmine.createSpyObj('$window', ['open']);
        return windowmock;
    });
});
```

Then you can also do checks on the mock in your tests to ensure it was or wasn't called.

```
expect(windowmock.open).toHaveBeenCalled(); // was called
expect(windowmock.open).not.toHaveBeenCalled(); // was not called
expect(windowmock.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(somevalue); // was called with some value
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you can just spyOn window.open; and expect it toHaveBeenCalled. No need to create a windowMock object.

Assuming you have the $scope loaded properly in beforeEach.

Start of the suite:

```
var window;

beforeEach(function() {
   inject(function($injector) {
      window = $injector.get('$window');
}});
```

In your spec:

```
spyOn($window, 'open');
expect($window.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
```